Making a 3d planet environment
I have a planet I have given a linear-gradient and I am trying to make rocks circle the perimeter of the planet while also having maybe some visible weather on the planet look like typhoons wandering around on it.
The goal is to make a planet with a orbiting rocks that the user can move the cursor to push slightly for a cool effect. That might require javascript but I'll tackle the first project first.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.planet,
.planet2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-60%, 0);
  height: 1100px;
  width: 900px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, #4a190290 20%, #7b222235, #2b2a29df);
  box-shadow: -20px -20px 40px 40px #801a1a6f inset, 0 0 20px 40px #cb221f90;
}

.astroid__belt {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 10%;
  left: calc(50% - 50%);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: perspective(1000px);
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.planet2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #ac4444, #b90f0fde, #542408b0);
  z-index: 3;
}

.astroid1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  left: calc(50% - 200px);
  background-color: #090606;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: animateAstroid 7s linear infinite;
  transform: tranzlateZ(550px);
}

.astroid__belt .astroid {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.astroid,
div {
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 70%;
}

@keyframes animateAstroid1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(75deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateAstroid2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
<div class="astroid__belt">
  <div class="astroid1"></div>
  <div class="astroid2"></div>
  <div class="astroid3"></div>
  <div class="astroid4"></div>
  <div class="astroid5"></div>
  <div class="astroid6"></div>
  <div class="astroid7"></div>
  <div class="astroid8"></div>
  <div class="astroid9"></div>
  <div class="astroid10"></div>
  <div class="astroid12"></div>
</div>
<div class="planet"></div>



I've tried getting the rings around the planet to circle around like a planet normally would, not just in a 2d space.

you mean astEroid. First I would make circles — a circle, then explore a bit of 3D principles in CSS. There's no rocks currently running around in your demo, so I guess there are some mistakes in the code or in providing a [mcve]...

Create a perspective wrapper. Create a transparent DIV.orbit pane rotated on the X axis by 90°. Inside it place the smaller asteroid DIV circle also rotated by 90° to counter the parent. Animate the parent to rotate linearly around its center, and to prevent its child asteroid to "pancake" as the parent rotates, you'll have to counter rotate on the Y axis the little asteroid - to keep it always as a circle (not an oval to line and back). If I got your question right - and that's "3D".

Then, instead of using classes like .asteroidN just use .asteroid - and use CSS properties (CSS Vars) to assign a different angle of inclination, speed, starting orbit position / angle for each of the rocks.

I'll give that a shot. Thanks. I revised the code a bit and I'll see if I can reproduce the same thing to show you if that problem still occurs. I didn't expect a reply so soon, but I appreciate it. I'll continue to problem solve and work on this.

And no, those "rocks" I made that were moving, I removed earlier. I know the aren't there. I'll keep you posted with a newer result as I progress.

Here's my take at creating an asteroid belt,
create .orbit elements for your .asteroid-s. Rotate the .orbit elements on the X axis and counter-rotate the asteroids. Animate the orbits on the Z axis and the asteroids on the Y axis by negative 360 degrees to counter-rotate and keep them in a circle shape.


* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #000;
}

.system {
  --size: 100;
  container-type: size;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 2000px;
  width:calc(var(--size) * 1cqmin);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.planet,
.orbit,
.asteroid {
  --y: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  height: calc(var(--size) * 1%);
  margin: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.planet {
  background: hsl(var(--hue) 50% 50%) linear-gradient(50deg, #0000 0%, #0000 45%, #000a 55%, #000e 100%);
}

.orbit {
  --duration: 6;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2vmin #fff4, inset 0 0 0 2cqmin #fff4;
  animation: orbit calc(var(--duration) * 1s) linear infinite;
  rotate: 1 var(--y) 0 80deg;
}

.asteroid {
  margin-left: calc(var(--size) * -0.5%);
  background: hsl(var(--hue) 50% 50%) linear-gradient(115deg, #0000 0%, #0000 45%, #000a 55%, #000e 100%);
  animation: asteroid calc(var(--duration) * 1s) linear infinite;
  rotate: 1 0 0 90deg;
}

@keyframes orbit { to { transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg); } }
@keyframes asteroid { to { transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -360deg); } }
<div class="system">
  <div class="planet" style="--size:40; --hue:10;"></div>
  
  <div class="orbit" style="--size:68; --y:-0.2; --duration:10;">
    <div class="asteroid" style="--size:8; --hue:20;"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="orbit" style="--size:80; --y:-0.2; --duration:6;">
    <div class="asteroid" style="--size:5; --hue:30;"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="orbit" style="--size:100; --y:-0.28; --duration:30;">
    <div class="asteroid" style="--size:10; --hue:190;"></div>
  </div>
</div>



Not perfect (a steeper orbit angle would reveal that gimballing the asteroids/moons to always face the "camera" gets quite hard...), but hopefully you can explore the idea further, like: create oval, elliptical orbits for certain rocks, and use a Bezier-curve animation instead of linear, play with other angles of inclination, etc.
The planets' weather (like typhoons, formations, etc.) can be achieved in the same way as for the asteroids, with the only difference that they should orbit the planet much closer, and you don't need to counter rotate the elements. Let them pancake/deform as they rotate on their orbits, just add a swirl rotation around their Z axis. Also a clipping area would be necessary to circumvent the flat nature of the orbiting element/pane.

Thanks for the help. I know how the variables here were manipulated but I had not gone that intensive with it before. I appreciate it. I'll have to practice doing that more often.  That does solve the problem. Now I can tweak some thing in the future and study this code. I appreciate it.
